# how to drag an image and show image in text area

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following textarea.

```
<textarea 
    style="width: 440px; height: 331px;" id="charlimit_text_a" name="message" id="droparea"
    placeholder="drag and drop your files here" listener="1" rows="20" cols="60" >
</textarea>
```

I wish to be able to drag an image into the text area, and it displays the image in the textarea.

I have been looking through the stackoverflow questions but I cannot seem to find an answer for what I am looking for. They all use divs, containers etc. but surely we can just use a text-area?

I wish to use simple javascript and I am using PHP as my server side language.

If anyone can step me in the right direction (not looking for solution) that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Textarea is meant for text and not for images. Leave drag and drop functionality, I doubt you can display images in textarea in general. My suggestion would be to use a `div` with `contentEditable` attribute to true to give the look and functionality of a textarea and then use the `div` as the drop target for images.

Comment: @fiveelements, okay will do that

Comment: @fiveelements is there a way to at least drag and drop the image into the text area and instead of the image displaying, just the image path? i.e. ``image.jpg``?

Comment: Yes, the image path or alt text, etc. can be shown in the textarea.

Comment: @fiveelements How may I go about achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example code which drags the images to a textarea and showss the image source.

```js
function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.event.target.src);
}
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    document.getElementById("display").innerText = document.getElementById("display").value + "  " + data;
}
function allow(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/rfr/logo_gmail_lockup_default_2x_r2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
<br />
<br />
Drag above imags here:
<textarea id="display" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allow(event)" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
```

#### Update:

The following example shows dragging files into a textarea and displays the file names.

```js
function drag(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.event.target.src);
}
function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = event.dataTransfer.files;
    for (file of data) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerText = document.getElementById("display").value + "  " + file.name;
    }
}
function allow(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
Drag files from your computer here:
<textarea id="display" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allow(event)" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
```

Comment: I don't get the path, i just get the image thumbnial when a image is not found

Comment: Just realised your code. I was meaning external image drag into text area. So if i drag an image from my folders into the text area.

Comment: Modified the same example to allow file drops from the filesystem.

Comment: this works well thanks. Although I am unable to drag it in with other text there. It only works if the first event in the textarea is the drop event. If I write some text and then drop the image it does not work. Is this an event restart problem?

Comment: So the last issue I am having, is once text is inside the textarea, the drag and drop doesnt work? What I am planning to do is the user can press a button to insert ``<img src="">`` and the user can then drag and drop the image path into the quotes. So it would look like ``<img src="image.png">``